# insert int into xml column sql

Tags: sql-server, xml

How do i go about insert an int parameter into a xml modify insert statement here is am example:

```
DECLARE @holdxml xml
DECLARE @myInt xml

set @myInt = 10

SET @holdxml = (SELECT CAST(VehicleManufacturerXML as xml) FROM VehicleManufacturers WHERE VehicleManufacturerID = 496);

SET @holdxml.modify('insert <VehicleManufacturerID>cast(@myInt, varchar(max))</VehicleManufacturerID> into (/VehicleManufacturers)[1]')

select @holdxml as x
```

ive tried convert, cast even found sql:variable but nothing seems to work? :(

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 (and that's one of the very few new XML related features, I believe), you could write something like:

```
DECLARE @holdxml xml
DECLARE @myInt xml

set @myInt = '<VehicleManufacturerID>abc</VehicleManufacturerID>'

SET @holdxml = (SELECT CAST(VehicleManufacturerXML as xml) FROM VehicleManufacturers WHERE VehicleManufacturerID = 496);

SET @holdxml.modify('insert sql:variable("@myInt") into (/VehicleManufacturers)[1]')

select @holdxml as x
```

but I'm afraid in 2005, this won't work (yet), AFAIK. Using the sql:variable in a "insert" XML DML statement is new in SQL Server 2008. You can use sql:variable in other places (e.g. `replace value of` and others) as of SQL Server 2005 and up.

Marc

PS: okay, so in 2005, I'm not 100% sure if this will work (don't have 2005 at hand anymore to test it), but you could try:

```
DECLARE @holdxml xml
DECLARE @myInt VARCHAR(MAX)

set @myInt = '<VehicleManufacturerID>abc</VehicleManufacturerID>'

SET @holdxml = (SELECT CAST(VehicleManufacturerXML as xml) FROM VehicleManufacturers WHERE VehicleManufacturerID = 496);

SET @holdxml.modify('insert ' + @myInt + ' into (/VehicleManufacturers)[1]')

select @holdxml as x
```

Just make your `@myInt` variable a VARCHAR(MAX) and concatenate together the string in the .modify statement.

Comment: sorry marc_s i didnt realise i hadn't updated the sample code @myInt was ment to be   123 .  and unfortunately that doesnt work i get the following error: 

Msg 8172, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The argument 1 of the xml data type method "modify" must be a string literal.

Comment: I want to specify the " into  (//node)[1] " part also dynamically. Can any let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i used the replace in the end,  tbh the column is actually an NTEXT with XML in it (old design from a previous site). i wanted to convert to XML and use all the lovely @XMLPARAM.modify features and then convert back but these is what i did in the end.

```
--Update Vehicle Options XML

DECLARE @VOXML as nvarchar(MAX)
SET @VOXML = (SELECT VehicleOptions.VehicleOptionXML FROM VehicleOptions WHERE VehicleOptions.VehicleOptionID = @VehOptionID)
SET @VOXML  = replace(@VOXML, '<VehicleOptionID></VehicleOptionID>', '<VehicleOptionID>'+cast(@VehOptionID as nvarchar(MAX))+'</VehicleOptionID>')
SET @VOXML  = replace(@VOXML, '<VehicleModelID title=""Model""></VehicleModelID>', '<VehicleModelID title=""Model"">'+cast(@VehModelID as nvarchar(MAX))+'</VehicleModelID>')

UPDATE VehicleOptions 
SET VehicleOptionXML = @VOXML
WHERE VehicleOptions.VehicleOptionID = @VehOptionID
```

interestingly enough tho, my second replace doesnt seem to get implemented. hmm i investigate some more...

cheers for response